# How to make the "time machine" work in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I heard that in Haskell we can use `MonadFix` to access a value that will be evaluated in the future. But I think `Monad`s are just syntactic sugar so there should be similar thing that can be implemented in pure functions. So I tried the following:

```
timemachine :: [a] -> (a -> Int -> b -> b) -> b -> b
timemachine al f b = result where
    ~(total, result) = foldr app (0,b) al
    app a (i,b1) = (i+1, f a (total - i) b1)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ timemachine "ddfdfeef" (\x i y -> (x,i):y) []
```

But the output is not expected:

```
[('d',1),('d',2),('f',3),('d',4),('f',5),('e',6),('e',7),('f',8)]
```

Ideally the result should be

```
[('d',8),('d',7),('f',6),('d',5),('f',4),('e',3),('e',2),('f',1)]
```

Am I did something wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect that result? Where does the laziness(?) come from your code?

Comment: Well my implementation may completely wrong but are there any right way to get the expected result? The point is that I need to access a value from the future - in the above example, the length of the list.

Comment: If I understand you properly, you're asking for a desugared version of some code using `MonadFix`. It seems only fair that you gave us the original one. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Skipping the part about `MonadFix`, it seems you want to use a value that at least partially needs itself to be constructed (`total` being based on the fold which in turn is based on `total`).

You're actually already doing that, only you're expectations don't line up with your folding! To see the problem you can change `timemachine` to

```
timemachine al f b = result where
   ~(total, result) = foldr app (0,b) al
   app a (i,b1) = (i+1, f a i b1)
```

which yields

```
[('d',7),('d',6),('f',5),('d',4),('f',3),('e',2),('e',1),('f',0)]
```

So `total-i` is working, it's just your accumulating `i`s that are not what you want.

Now, why? Well, you use a `foldr` which works out to something like:

```
app 'd' (app 'd' (app 'f' ... (app 'f' (0,b)))))))))
```

So the counting that `app` is doing is being worked from the right of the list. if we instead change it to a `foldl` which works the list from the other side, and change some of the rest of the code to line up with it:

```
timemachine :: [a] -> (a -> Int -> b -> b) -> b -> b
timemachine al f b = result where
  ~(total, result) = foldl app (0,b) al
  app (i,b1) a = (i+1, f a (total-i) b1)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ timemachine "ddfdfeef" (\x i y -> y++[(x,i)]) []
```

You get what you wanted:

```
[('d',8),('d',7),('f',6),('d',5),('f',4),('e',3),('e',2),('f',1)]
```

Comment: Shall I use `foldl'` instead? I heard that `foldl` is to be avoided.

Comment: Usually using `foldl'` is preferred to `foldl` since it's strict in it's accumulator, and when you fold to the left you're normally not interested in laziness. In this case however, there are two issues with that:
1. Our accumulator is a pair, and `seq` (used by `fold'`) only evaluates to HNF, which `app` already does, so there's no strictness gain there.
2. We ARE interested in laziness, it's what makes this work. If we would fold with something like `deepseq`, it'd try to evaluate the resulting list all too early, and it wouldn't finish.

Comment: @EarthEngine excuse the poor formatting of that answer, I didn't know about the 5-min comment edit window. I hope it still clear enough to answer your question!